# Can I get a DHCP address from within a container via the DHCP server the host is on?

Tags: networking, systemd, container, systemd-nspawn

I have a host (ubuntu xenial) running a container via `systemd-nspawn` (also xenial):

```
systemd-nspawn --directory=gogs --network-macvlan=ens192 --boot
```

`ens192` is the host interface which gets its IP address via DHCP.

From within the container, I would like to get an IP address which would be provided by the network DHCP, the one who previously provided it to the host (I first need to use a MAC address which is registered with the DHCP server):

```
root@git:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: mv-ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ether d2:b9:c3:77:25:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0

root@git:~# ifconfig mv-ens192 hw ether aa:a0:a0:a0:a0:01

root@git:~# ifconfig mv-ens192 up

root@git:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: mv-ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:50:56:bb:60:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:febb:603f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@git:~# dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/mv-ens192/aa:a0:a0:a0:a0:01
Sending on   LPF/mv-ens192/aa:a0:a0:a0:a0:01
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on mv-ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xd36b8c1e)
DHCPDISCOVER on mv-ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xd36b8c1e)
```

The discovery does not go though.

**What is the reason this fails?**

The DHCP discovery packet goes to the host NIC, which then should dispatch it further (it should not be different from the call the host is making when requesting its own IP).

Note: when running a `tshark`on the **host**, I see the container's request:

```
634 8.404019212      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP 342 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xd36b8c1e
```